# Is there an elegant C++ implementation of fixed-size allocator?

Tags: c++, performance, object, memory-management, c++11

I think a C++ library is "elegant" if the number of header files which must be included are as less as possible.

I know there have been existing fixed-size allocators like `Loki::SmallObjectAllocator` and `boost::pool`. Although both are excellent, I think they are not elegant and not easy to be seamlessly integrated into projects.

Most times, I only need a little part of boost library, but I have to install the whole library on my machine. For example, if I want to use boost::pool, I hope to just include **ONE** header file `boost_pool.h` and the work is done. Because I think a fixed-size allocator should not be so dependent on too many other components. In my opinion, ideal code should look like the following:

```
#include <boost_pool.h>

int main()
{
   boost::pool<int> p;
   int* v = p.allocate();
}
```

Does there exist such a library?

Comment: Have you looked at [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)? Not exactly the same, but it can easily be used as a starting point to shove everything into a single header.

Comment: "I hope to just include ONE header file `boost_pool.h`" - so, do the work once and put all related things in there? Seriously.

Comment: Thanks. I viewed bcp just now, but find it is not yet easy to use. I think boost has too many unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: @Xeo, Yes. The less dependent, the more elegant; I think so.

Comment: seems like you could install boost long time ago, but you needed just one thing and you decided it's not worth the effort. and the same every time you need something from boost. probably, it's time to install it finally?

Comment: Possibly the word you're looking for is "stand-alone" rather than "elegant". Boost sees "elegance" in a different way -- code is shared between different Boost components rather than being duplicated by every component that needs to do the same thing. The result, of course, is internal dependencies within Boost.

Comment: @Andy, I seldom use boost because my most projects are kernel-based. But I know boost is an excellent library, so I want reuse it.

Comment: @Steve, you are correct in most cases; but I think a fixed-size allocator should not be dependent to too many other components.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I believe cross-platformness is the main thing that prevent Boost libs from being "stand-alone". A lot of Boost libs are independent by its nature, but it's still difficult to use them out of normal Boost setup.

Comment: @AndyT: certainly some of the commonly-used stuff in Boost is defined differently in different platforms. I'm pretty sure that you can write a pool allocator (for that matter, a lot of Boost features) without a heavy platform isolation layer. But once you've *got* a fully-featured platform isolation layer you generally use it rather than re-implement the little bits of platform isolation that each component requires. Similarly for convenience tools like `BOOST_FOREACH`, once you have them you wouldn't avoid using them just in order to make your boost component more stand-alone.

Answer (score 5):

You are welcome to [mine](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html).  Whether it is elegant or not, you can decide.  But it is just one short header dependent upon just a couple of small standard headers.  The allocator meets the C++11 allocator requirements, which are a subset of the C++03 allocator requirements.  You can always add the C++03 boiler plate if you need it.

Comment: Note for Windows users: note that stateful allocators do not work yet in Debug mode under Visual C++ 2012 November CTP. There is some debug checking that uses `Allocator::construct` rather than `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct`

Answer (score 2):

Are you using GCC? It's standard library comes with a few fixed-size allocators as extensions, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#allocator.ext

They're fairly standalone (not sure about elegant, it's a long time since I looked at their code properly)