# String type with max length

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdstring

I need to implement a C++11 or C++14 type STRING that acts just like `std:string`, but has the following additional constraints/features:

1. WIDTH parameter specified during declaration. STRING will
   throw exception if its length is greater than WIDTH
2. Optional FIXED parameter specified during declaration. STRING will throw exception if its length is not equal to WIDTH

In all other respects, STRING is supposed to behave just like `std::string` and expose the same member functions as `std:string` (such as `.append()` etc..).

My first instinct was to use a template class `STRING` that holds a `std::string`, like so:

```
template<int WIDTH= 0, bool FIXED = false>
class STRING {
    static_assert(WIDTH >= 0, "WIDTH of STRING cannot be negative.");
public:
    STRING() : value{} { }

    STRING(const std::string &s) { if (is_valid(s)) value = s; }

    STRING(const char c[]) { if (is_valid(c)) value = c; }

    STRING& operator=(const std::string& s){ if (is_valid(s)) value = s;}
    operator std::string() const { return value; }


    std::string value;

private:
    bool is_valid(const std::string &s) {
        if (WIDTH && s.length() > WIDTH)
            throw std::length_error{"STRING assignment failed. STRING too long."};
        if (FIXED && s.length() != WIDTH)
            throw std::length_error{"STRING assignment failed. STRING has wrong length."};
        return true;
    }
};
```

However, the above `STRING` template class does not expose `std::string` member functions and I do not want to re-implement the entire `std::basic_char` function set, so I think my approach is fundamentally wrong. I suspect somehow extending `std::string` might be better, but it seems a little scary to "mess" with the standard library types.

I am not sure what the best approach would be here and pointers in the right direction would be more than welcome.

Comment: What happens to the width when you need to do something like `string1 + string2`?

Comment: Your first instinct is right (please make `std::string value;` private). You observe the ugliness of a string class based on std::string, exposing the same (and extended) functionality.

Comment: @user2357112: Adding a `STRING<7>` and a `STRING<5>` creates a `STRING<12>`, obviously. The "fixed" bit is slightly less obvious: the result is fixed if and only if both inputs are fixed.

Comment: @MSalters: See, that might be obvious from your perspective, but to someone with a different use case in mind, it might be obvious that adding a `STRING<7>` and a `STRING<7>` produces another `STRING<7>` and adding a `STRING<7>` and a `STRING<5>` is a compile-time error.

Comment: @user2357112: There's a strong consensus, even across programming languages that _if_ strings have a binary operator `+`, then it's concatenation. Famously, Java has only case of operator overloading, and it's `String+String` Python too uses `+`.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, and I'm talking about concatenation too. Note that the WIDTH in this question is a maximum length, not the exact length of the string. Concatenating a length-2, WIDTH-5 string and a length-3, WIDTH-5 string could reasonably be expected to produce a length-5, WIDTH-5 string.

Comment: @user2357112: thank you for pointing out yet another issue with my STRING<WIDTH> class. I will have to come up with a different solution altogether for my use case.

Comment: @user2357112: You're mixing run-time and compile-time properties. The return type of `operator+(STRING<N>, STRING<M>)` is `STRING<N+M>`, determined at compile time. The maximum length of the concatenated string is the sum of maximum lengths of both sides.

Comment: @MSalters: No, I'm well aware of what's determined at runtime and what's determined at compile-time. You have to consider *why* this WIDTH exists. Maybe you have to stuff these strings into a fixed-width database column or something. If you want to concatenate values from two rows and stuff them into a single row, that column isn't going to get any bigger. I don't know what use case you have in mind that motivates adding the WIDTH values together, and I don't know what the questioner's use case is. It's hard to say what the right decision is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is through modifying the allocator template argument. Note that `std::string` is a shorthand for

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

Inside the allocator you can put functionality to check for overflow or length.

Look at [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455670/is-there-an-elegant-c-implementation-of-fixed-size-allocator) on advice on how to write a custom allocator. [**Howard Hinnant's website**](http://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html) has an example on how to limit the boilerplate you need to duplicate.

As remarked by @rici, most implementations will use the short-string-optimization (SSO). This means that the string class will have a `union` of a small stack-based storage (typically 24 bytes or so) and three pointers into the heap. This means that for small strings, the supplied allocator maybe ignored altogether. That would in practice mean that you could not limit strings to be very small (below the SSO threshold).

Comment: And short string optimization means there might not be an allocation.

Comment: @rici: thanks for your helpful comment. I will think of a different solution for my use case.